# Header content disappearing when CSS applied for responsive layout (bootstrap file included in html)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am setting a responsive layout for my personal website, which has worked in a simple example. However I am not getting the same results. It may have something to do with including the Bootstrap files in my html. Below is the html and css code for the responsive layout:

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <a href="/" id="logo">
            <h1>Brian Weber</h1>
            <h2>Engineer | Python Programmer</h2>
        </a>

        <!-- Navigation bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
<!--            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brian Weber</a>
            <p>Engineer</p> -->
            </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {

/*********************************
HEADER
*********************************/

  .navbar .navbar-default {
     float: right; 
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 5%;
    text-align: right;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #logo h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }

  #logo h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  header {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #599a68;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

}
```

When I check the code in a browser, the h1 and h2 text do not appear. However when I inspect the element there are placeholders for where the text should be. The text color is already set to black in the main.css. My question is how would I fix this problem so that the layout looks like the picture below? I am thinking maybe there is an issue with the bootstrap files where they are overriding the CSS code.

[Correct format for header and navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzrNJ.png)

[h1 and h2 text disappearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oPth.png)

Comment: Please add demo link to better understand.

Comment: Here is a link to the site: http://www.brianwweber.com/ refer to the homepage for the issue I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your style

```
#logo
{
z-index:1;
position:relative;
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. and in your style navbar-default hide the h1 and h2 that's why it's not looking

Answer (score 0):

Make .navbar-default float right when in the larger views. It was covering up the left floating div that contained your name etc.

Comment: I already have .navbar-default float right when the screen width is bigger than 660px. If you have fixed the problem, could you post what you changed/added?

Comment: .navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

This is the CSS being applied to navbar-default.  The only media CSS I see targeting it is this:

@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

Comment: In responsive.css there is a rule for float right when the screen is bigger than 660px. I changed the min-width to 768px and added z-index: 1 and position: relative. Now it works fine.

Comment: The rule wasn't getting through the stack maybe. I would suggest against editing the bootstrap CSS directly and just adding your own stylesheet to override anything you want from bootstrap.  You will end up with a lot of issues otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It seems like I was having more trouble when I directly edited the bootstrap css. For now on I'm linking an external style sheet to customize the layout. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` and `z-index` for logo.

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: left;
  width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```